# Is it possible to embed dependencies into a command line tool?

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line, dependencies

I am building a c++ command-line tool in xcode and the tool depends on a variety of external libraries. The project builds just fine, but is still dependent on the libraries. I'd like it to be usable on several computers that have the same architecture, without needing to install the dependency tree. Is this possible?

After much searching I've found several answers similar to the following link, but these have to do with building an app bundle and not a command-line tool. Any insight is very helpful.

[dynamic libraries in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832316/dynamic-libraries-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most platforms have a distinction between static and dynamic libraries.  You need to find static versions of your dependencies and link to those rather than the dynamic ones.  Linker switches often control that process.

The C++ standard doesn't say anything about how that might work.