# MacOS -- how to link a dynamic library with a relative path using gcc/ld

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, ld, dynamic-library

If you are trying to understand dynamic linking, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode) is likely to be of interest.

One of the answers to that question provides a wonderful example of creating and using a dynamic library.  Based on it, I some simple files:

main.c:

```
extern void someFunction (int x);

int main (int argc, char** argv ) {
    someFunction(666);
}
```

mylibrary.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunction (int x) {
    printf ("\nsomeFunction called with x=%d\n", x);
}
```

makefile:

```
main: mylibrary.c main.c
    gcc -c mylibrary.c
    gcc -dynamiclib -current_version 1.0 mylibrary.o -o libmylibrary.dylib
    gcc -c main.c
    gcc -v main.o ./libmylibrary.dylib -o main

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm main
    rm *.dylib
```

So far, everything works great.  If I make and then enter ./main at the command prompt, I see the expected output:

```
someFunction called with x=666
```

Now, I want to mix things up a little.  I've created a directory hidelib, which is a subdirectory of my main directory.  And I'm adding one line to my makefile:

```
main: mylibrary.c main.c
    gcc -c mylibrary.c
    gcc -dynamiclib -current_version 1.0 mylibrary.o -o libmylibrary.dylib
    gcc -c main.c
    mv libmylibrary.dylib hidelib     # this is the new line

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm main
    rm hidelib/*.*
```

Now, I want to add another line to the makefile so it will find libmylibrary.dylib in the hidelib subdirectory.  I want to be able to run ./main in the same way.  How can I do that?

EDIT:  Thanks for the response.  Having lots of options is wonderful, but a beginner just wants one concrete option that works.  Here is what I am trying for the last line, but clearly I don't understand something.  The makefile executes without errors, but at runtime it says "library not found."

```
    gcc main.o -rpath,'$$ORIGIN/hidelib' -lmylibrary -o main
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One concrete option that works would be to set the `install_name` flag when linking the `.dylib`.

```
gcc -dynamiclib -install_name '$(CURDIR)/hidelib/libmylibrary.dylib' -current_version 1.0 mylibrary.o -o libmylibrary.dylib
```

Then you can just link to the library normally:

```
gcc main.o -L '$(CURDIR)/hidelib' -lmylibrary -o main
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably need the `-L`  compiler/linker flag which adds to the search path for libraries.

Are trying to move things after linking, you'll need a `dyld` environment variable for where to search. `man dyld` and you should be able to get more information on `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other environment variables.

Typically, though, you set the install name of the library before linking to something with the `-install_name` linker flag to something like `@rpath/mylibrary.dylib` as the value, then set the run path search paths on the main executable while compiling with the `-rpath` flag to `@executable_path/hidelib`.

For more information see `install_name_tool` and the `-rpath` & `-install_name` arguments of `ld`.

Basically, there are a lot of options for what you're trying to do.