# how to create a dylib on mac

Tags: macos, dylib

I created a dll in Windows. Now i wanted to created something similar on mac/iPhone. I figured out, we can bundle a dylib with the app and that will be the best way to do it.

Firstly, is this the right approach?

Secondly, I'm trying to figure out how to create a dylib and use it in my app/xproj. Could someone please point me to any tutorial or if this query is already answered, please point me to it.

Thank you,
Vinu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a dynamic library (dylib) with Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode)