# How to create a .dylib of a full C++ project?

Tags: c++, xcode, maple

I have a project written in C++ and I want to call some functions of it from Maple. Searching about possible solutions, I found the one to create .dylib from the C++ files and then call this .dylib from Maple.

I was able to create a .dylib from a single C++ file and use its functions from Maple, following this: [How do I create a dynamic library (dylib) with Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode)

Now, I'm wondering if I can do it with a full project. I saw that maybe I could do it using Xcode (I have the version 6.4), but I don't know how...

Someone could help me? Any help is appreciate, thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a bit of a broad question, but it's certainly possible from Xcode.  There should be a template for just such a project.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Between all templates given by Xcode, which one could be more useful, or better for what I want to do?

Comment: I am not near Xcode at the moment, but it's probably called "shared library".

Comment: If I try to create a new project (and add what I have afterwards), for

OS > Framework & Library, 

I have "Cocoa Framework", "Library", "Bundle" and "XPC Service". Should I go to "Library", right?

Comment: But when I'm creating it asks for "Framework": "Cocoa", "STL (C++ Library)" and "None (Plain C/C++ Library)". Which one should I use?

Comment: Have a look at this other [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201797/how-to-use-dylib-library-and-hpp-header-file-in-ios-project/38203901#38203901)